# jqerymobile listview item onclick

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a jquerymobile listview like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li onclick="accionesDocumento('action li','none')"> <a onclick="accionesDocumento('action a-onclick','none')">Pruebas</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this jscript function

```
function accionesDocumento(tclink,tcAccion) {
    alert(tclink);
}
```

My problem is that onclick event never fires. some ideas ?

NOTE: you could see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9386M/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9386M/20/)

```
<script>
  function accionesDocumento(tclink,tcAccion) {
    alert(tclink);
  }
</script>    

<ul data-role="listview">
  <li><a href="javascript:accionesDocumento('Hola','mundo')">Pruebas</a></li>
</ul>
```

complete example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="javascript:accionesDocumento('Hola','mundo')">Pruebas</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <script>
    function accionesDocumento(tclink,tcAccion) {
      alert(tclink);
    }
    </script>
  </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```